# This systemd service I wrote after following documentation for a Unturned server won't work any help?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, systemd

What is wrong with my script/code or whatever and how would I go about fixing it?

Ubuntu server 20.04

Source to original documentation: https://wiki.smartlydressedgames.com/wiki/Linux_dedicated_server
[image: Code]

[image: Errors]

Comment: journalctl -xe and systemctl status your-service will be helpful.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.